# Reading Mishnah Torah on Hoshana Rabba

Tags: sources-mekorot, pentateuch-chumash, hoshana-rabbah, deuteronomy

There is a minhag that many have to read in shul from a Sefer Torah the entire Chumash of Davarim on the night of Hoshanah Rabbah. What is the first makor (source) for this minhag and what is the reason for it?

Comment: See [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/mahanaim/hoshaana1-2.htm)  a large research about the minhag